# How to programmatically run sequelize migrations

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

The documentation for sequelize seems out of date as they no longer support running migrations from sequelize itself, but instead relies on sequelize-cli.  Is there an example of how to use sequeliz-cli programmatically to run the latest migrations?  All the documentation seems to be focused on using the client in a shell.

db.js seems to have the function db:migrate that perhaps I can include.

https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/lib/tasks/db.js

Comment: If I understood you correctly, isn't this what umzug was created for ? https://github.com/sequelize/umzug

Comment: it does - but I'd like to use all the sequelize configuration that's built in to share connection strings objects and what not.. rather than use umzug alone and re-implement the sequelize configuration modules.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Update: @phil-court's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67065076/109538) is better.**

Original answer here for posterity...

---

I dug into the code for the [`sequelize db:migrate` command](https://github.com/sequelize/cli/blob/master/src/commands/migrate.js), and there's enough going on there that, IMHO, the simplest/best approach is to just run the command in a child process.  Here's the code I used for this (as an await'ed Promise):

```
const {exec} = require('child_process');

await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const migrate = exec(
    'sequelize db:migrate',
    {env: process.env},
    err => (err ? reject(err): resolve())
  );

  // Forward stdout+stderr to this process
  migrate.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  migrate.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
});
```

Comment: As the node server itself starts from the code unlike some languages like PHP where server runs always, we are forced to run the migrations only when the node is running when you have table creation logic based on the model defined and not from the migration and this is the best way to go with it. Thank you very much

Comment: Very elegant solution to a slightly complex problem

Comment: Doesn't work for sqlite in memory :)

Answer (score 19):

I had this exact same problem and implemented the accepted answer. However I ran into concurrency issues while running this as a separate process, especially during tests.

I think this question is rather old, but it still appears very high on search results. Today it's a *much* better idea to run it using umzug.
It's the library that sequelize uses to manage migrations on it's end, and is suggested by [the docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/migrations.html#programmatic-usage).

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Umzug = require('umzug');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { sequelize } = require('../models/index.js');

const umzug = new Umzug({
  migrations: {
    // indicates the folder containing the migration .js files
    path: path.join(process.cwd(), './migrations'),
    // inject sequelize's QueryInterface in the migrations
    params: [
      sequelize.getQueryInterface(),
      Sequelize,
    ],
  },
  // indicates that the migration data should be store in the database
  // itself through sequelize. The default configuration creates a table
  // named `SequelizeMeta`.
  storage: 'sequelize',
  storageOptions: {
    sequelize,
  },
});

async function migrate() {
  return umzug.up();
}

async function revert() {
  return umzug.down({ to: 0 });
```

And with that you can do everything you need to do with migrations without resorting to spawning a different process, which opens you to all sorts of race conditions and problems down the line. Read more about how to use umzug with the docs on [github](https://github.com/sequelize/umzug)

Comment: Nice, elegant solution.  'Wish I'd known how to do this when I originally encountered this problem.  Thanks for sharing.

Comment: Nice, but getting an 'Umzug is not a constructor' error on the latest version.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I did. It is not yet extensively tested, and probably can be optimized further:

```
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const db = new Sequelize('main', 'test', 'test', {
dialect: 'sqlite',
// SQLite only
storage: 'db.db'
});

async function checkForMigrations() {
let migrations = fs.readdirSync(__dirname + '/../migrations');
let completedMigrations = await db.query("SELECT * FROM `SequelizeMeta`", {type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT});
for (let name in completedMigrations) {
    if (completedMigrations.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        let index = migrations.indexOf(completedMigrations[name].name);
        if (index !== -1) {
            migrations.splice(index, 1);
        }
    }
}

for(let i = 0, c = migrations.length; i < c; i++){
   let migration = require(__dirname + '/../migrations/' + migrations[i]);
   migration.up(db.queryInterface, Sequelize);
   await db.query("INSERT INTO `SequelizeMeta` VALUES(:name)", {type: Sequelize.QueryTypes.INSERT, replacements: {name: migrations[i]}})
}
}
```