# How to create postgres database and run migration when docker-compose up

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm setting up a simple backend that perform CRUD action with postgres database and want to create database and migration automatically when the docker-compose up runs.

I have already tried to add below code to *Dockerfile* or *entrypoint.sh* but none of them work.

```
createdb --host=localhost -p 5432 --username=postgres --no-password pg_development
createdb db:migrate
```

This code will work if run separately after docker is fully up

I have already tried to add `- ./db-init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d` to the volumes but that didn't work either

This is the *Dockerfile*

```
FROM node:10.12.0

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /restify-pg
WORKDIR /restify-pg

EXPOSE 1337

ENTRYPOINT [ "./entrypoint.sh" ]
```

This is my *docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:11.2"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgData:/var/lib/psotgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
      POSTGRES_DB: pg_development

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/restify-pg
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
```

*entrypoint.sh* (in here I get `createdb: command not found`)

```
#!/bin/bash

cd app

createdb --host=localhost -p 5432 --username=postgres --no-password pg_development
sequelize db:migrate

npm install
npm run dev
```

I expect that when I run docker, the migration and the db creation would happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> entrypoint.sh (in here I get createdb: command not found)

Running `createdb` in the nodejs container will not work because it is postgres specific command and it's not installed by default in the nodejs image.

If you specify `POSTGRES_DB: pg_development` env var on postgres container, the database will be [created automatically when the container starts](https://docs.docker.com/samples/library/postgres/#start-a-postgres-instance). So no need to run `createdb` anyway in `entrypoint.sh` that is mounted in the nodejs container.

In order to make `sequelize db:migrate` work you need to:

- add `sequelize-cli` to dependencies in `package.json`
- run `npm install` so it gets installed
- run `npx sequelize db:migrate`

Here is a proposal:

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: "postgres:11.2"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - ./pgData:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD:
      POSTGRES_DB: pg_development

  app:
    working_dir: /restify-pg
    entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "./entrypoint.sh"]
    image: node:10.12.0
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    volumes:
      - .:/restify-pg
    environment:
      DB_HOST: db
```

```
# package.json

{
  ...
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "pg": "^7.9.0",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^5.2.9",
    "sequelize-cli": "^5.4.0"
  }
}
```

```
# entrypoint.sh

npm install
npx sequelize db:migrate
npm run dev
```

Comment: ```npx sequelize db:migrate``` worked beautiflly but i still can't craete pg_development db and ```npx sequelize db:migrate``` also errors me that can't find pg_development

Comment: When you do `docker-compose up` please read through the logs to understand what's going on. You should see `db_1   | CREATE DATABASE` if the postgres container creates the database on initialization. Another thing to try would be adding `npx sequelize db:create` to `entrypoint.sh` (you might need to remove `POSTGRES_DB: pg_development` env var from `db` container).

Answer (score 0):

If you can run your migrations from nodejs instead of docker then consider [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30848530/how-to-programmatically-run-sequelize-migrations) instead